# .map() don't is not a function in typescript

Tags: typescript, typeorm

Objects, `{}` in javascript does not have the method `.map()`, it is available only data type as `Array` `[]` so I though the below data format is correct but why I can not use `.map()`.

I want to query array data and using `.map()` function to get it's value as below

I get error messages: **.map() don't is not a function in typescript**

```
const startDate = [];
const endDate = [];
let query;
query = this.createQueryBuilder("LeaveRequest")
      .where("LeaveRequest.employeeId = :employeeId", { employeeId })
      .getMany();
query.leaveRequest.map(function (leaveRequest) {
      leaveRequest.map(function (values) {
      startDate.push(values.startDate);
      endDate.push(values.endDate);
  });
});
return {startDate, endDate};
```

Data format
When I do `return query;` I got below format;

```
[
  {
    "id": 40,
    "createdAt": "2018-07-23T10:01:49.939Z",
    "updatedAt": "2018-07-23T10:01:49.939Z",
    "createdBy": 1,
    "updatedBy": null,
    "state": 1,
    "version": 1,
    "requestStatus": 1,
 },
{
    "id": 40,
    "createdAt": "2018-07-23T10:01:49.939Z",
    "updatedAt": "2018-07-23T10:01:49.939Z",
    "createdBy": 1,
    "updatedBy": null,
    "state": 1,
    "version": 1,
    "requestStatus": 1,
},
{
    "id": 40,
    "createdAt": "2018-07-23T10:01:49.939Z",
    "updatedAt": "2018-07-23T10:01:49.939Z",
    "createdBy": 1,
    "updatedBy": null,
    "state": 1,
    "version": 1,
    "requestStatus": 1,
}
]
```

You can see the images

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All your above answer is almost correct but you may forget the `async` and `await` 
because when I applied those all its properties work as well.

```
 async functionName() {
    const startDate = [];
    const endDate = [];
    let query;
    query = await this.createQueryBuilder("LeaveRequest")
          .where("LeaveRequest.employeeId = :employeeId", { employeeId })
          .getMany();
    query.leaveRequest.map(function (leaveRequest) {
          leaveRequest.map(function (values) {
          startDate.push(values.startDate);
          endDate.push(values.endDate);
      });
    });
    return {startDate, endDate};
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Define the type of `query` and initialize it, so even if `getMany` returns null initialized value won't allow having that `.map()` not a function error

```
let query: Array<any> = new Array<any>(size);
```

using `any` type is not advisable if you have defined your class type for the return result of the array then use that class type and have a size for the array (it's optional)

Use `forEach` instead of `map` if you aren't returning anything.

`forEach()` method doesn’t actually return anything (undefined). It simply calls a provided function on each element in your array.

The `map()` method will call a provided function on every element in the array. The difference is that `map()` utilizes return values and actually returns a new Array of the same size.

```js
let query = [
  {
    "id": 40,
    "createdAt": "2018-07-23T10:01:49.939Z",
    "updatedAt": "2018-07-23T10:01:49.939Z",
    "createdBy": 1,
    "updatedBy": null,
    "state": 1,
    "version": 1,
    "requestStatus": 1,
 },
{
    "id": 40,
    "createdAt": "2018-07-23T10:01:49.939Z",
    "updatedAt": "2018-07-23T10:01:49.939Z",
    "createdBy": 1,
    "updatedBy": null,
    "state": 1,
    "version": 1,
    "requestStatus": 1,
},
{
    "id": 40,
    "createdAt": "2018-07-23T10:01:49.939Z",
    "updatedAt": "2018-07-23T10:01:49.939Z",
    "createdBy": 1,
    "updatedBy": null,
    "state": 1,
    "version": 1,
    "requestStatus": 1,
}
];
let startDate = [];
let endDate = [];

 
query.forEach(leaveRequest =>  {
      startDate.push(leaveRequest.createdAt);
      endDate.push(leaveRequest.updatedAt);  
});
console.log(startDate);
console.log(endDate);
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not need inner map, just this would do,

```
query.map(leaveRequest =>  {
      startDate.push(leaveRequest.createdAt);
      endDate.push(leaveRequest.updatedAt);  
});
```

**`DEMO`**

```js
let query = [
  {
    "id": 40,
    "createdAt": "2018-07-23T10:01:49.939Z",
    "updatedAt": "2018-07-23T10:01:49.939Z",
    "createdBy": 1,
    "updatedBy": null,
    "state": 1,
    "version": 1,
    "requestStatus": 1,
 },
{
    "id": 40,
    "createdAt": "2018-07-23T10:01:49.939Z",
    "updatedAt": "2018-07-23T10:01:49.939Z",
    "createdBy": 1,
    "updatedBy": null,
    "state": 1,
    "version": 1,
    "requestStatus": 1,
},
{
    "id": 40,
    "createdAt": "2018-07-23T10:01:49.939Z",
    "updatedAt": "2018-07-23T10:01:49.939Z",
    "createdBy": 1,
    "updatedBy": null,
    "state": 1,
    "version": 1,
    "requestStatus": 1,
}
];
let startDate = [];
let endDate = [];

 
query.map(leaveRequest =>  {
      startDate.push(leaveRequest.createdAt);
      endDate.push(leaveRequest.updatedAt);  
});
console.log(startDate);
```

Comment: steal got "message": "Uncaught Exception: query.map is not a function"

Comment: Look at the data above, the data you provided and you have is different i think

Comment: I' using typeorm and those data format was return from `getMany` function.
`return query.getMany();`

Comment: post your data what that query returns

Comment: I post  to update my query a image that you can see it

Comment: i guess the query is null in the above case. can you see the data?

Comment: I post an image you can see that it is not null I get data as above format .

Comment: if thats the case above should work. as you can see a working demo

Comment: Then the answer above is almost right. That's not *query.map* but *query.getMany().map*